# Condition on probability measure

Tags: real-analysis

Let X be a compact metrizable space and $\{\mu_{n}\}$ be a sequence of Borel measure on $X$ with $\mu_{n}(X)=1$ for every n. Consider the linear map $\phi:C(X)\rightarrow \mathcal{l}^{\infty}(\mathbb{N})$ defined by $\phi(f)=(\int_{X}fd\mu_{n})_{n}$. What conditions on the sequence $\{\mu_{n}\}$ are equivalent to $\phi$ being an isometry?

I have shown that  $|\int_{X}fd\mu_{n}|\leq\int_{X}|f|d\mu_{n}\leq\int_{X}\|f\|_{u}d\mu_{n}=\|f\|_{u}$, which means $\|\phi(f)\|\leq\|f\|_{u}$.

But for the other direction, I don't know what condition is required and how to prove it.

Comment: It suffices for the $\mu_n$'s to be a dense set of delta masses, i.e. $\mu_n = \delta_{x_n}$ with $\{x_n\}$ dense.

Comment: $\phi$ is an isometry if and only if $\{\delta_x:x\in X\} \subseteq \overline{\{\mu_n : n \geq 1\}}$, where the closure is taken with respect to the weak-$*$ topology.

Comment: @Sangchul Lee Could you give me a full proof to show this is true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, I have $|\int_{X}fd\mu_{n}|\leq\int_{X}|f|d\mu_{n}\leq\int_{X}\|f\|_{u}d\mu_{n}=\|f\|_{u}$, which means $\|\varphi(f)\|\leq\|f\|_{u}$.

Conversely, since $X$ is compact metrizable space, I can find a countable dense subset $\{x_{n}\}$, define $\mu_{n}=\delta_{x_{n}}$, then $\varphi=(f(x_{n}))_{n}$. Since $\{x_{n}\}$ is dense in $X$ and $f$ is continuous, for every $\epsilon>0$, I can find that for every $x \in X$, there is some $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|f(x_{n})|>|f(x)|-\epsilon$. Then $\|\varphi(f)\|\geq\|f\|_{u}-\epsilon$. Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, then $\|\varphi(f)\|\geq\|f\|_{u}$.

Thus, $\varphi$ is an isometry.

Answer (score 0):

We prove:

> $\phi$ is an isometry if and only if $\{\delta_x : x \in X\} \subseteq \overline{\{\mu_n : n \geq 1\}}$, where the closure is taken with respect to the weak-$*$ topology.

$(\Leftarrow)$ : By the compactness of $X$, we can pick $x \in X$ so that $\|f\|_u = |f(x)|$. Then for each $\epsilon > 0$, we can pick $\mu_n$ so that $\left|\int_X f\,\mathrm{d}\mu_n - \int_X f\,\mathrm{d}\delta_x\right|<\epsilon$. From this, we get $\|\phi(f)\|\geq\left|\int_X f\,\mathrm{d}\mu_n\right|>\|f\|_u-\epsilon$. Since this is true for any $\epsilon > 0$, the desired claim follows.

$(\Rightarrow)$ : Let $x \in X$ be arbitrary. We want to show that $\delta_x \in \overline{\{\mu_n : n \geq 1\}}$. Since this is obvious when $\delta_x = \mu_n$ for some $n$, we may assume otherwise. We will prove that $\delta_x$ is a weak-$*$ limit point of the sequence $(\mu_n)$.

Let $f \in C(X)$ and $k \geq 1$. Then there exists an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $|f(y) - f(x)| < 1/k$ for all $y \in U$. Also, we can pick $\chi \in C(X)$ so that $\mathbf{1}_{\{x\}} \leq \chi \leq \mathbf{1}_U$. Since $\|\phi(\chi)\| = \|\chi\|_u = 1$, there exists $\mu_{n_k}$ so that $\int_X \chi \, \mathrm{d}\mu_{n_k} > 1-1/k$. Then

\begin{align*}
\left| \int_X f \, \mathrm{d}\mu_{n_k} - \int_X f \, \mathrm{d}\delta_x \right|
&\leq \int_X (1-\chi)|f| \, \mathrm{d}\mu_{n_k} + \int_X |f - f(x)|\chi \, \mathrm{d}\mu_{n_k} \\
&\leq \|f\|_u \int_X (1-\chi) \, \mathrm{d}\mu_{n_k} + \sup_{y\in U}|f(y)-f(x)| \\
&\leq \frac{\|f\|_u + 1}{k}.
\end{align*}

Moreover, since $\mu_n(\{x\}) < 1$ for all $n$, the indices $(n_k)$ cannot be bounded. So we may assume that $(n_k)$ is strictly increasing, i.e., $(\mu_{n_k})$ is a subsequence of $(\mu_n)$. This tells that $\int_X f \, \mathrm{d}\mu_k \to f(x)$ as $k\to\infty$. Now fix a countable dense subset $\mathcal{D}$ of $C(X)$. Then by the diagonal argument, we can find a subsequence $(\mu_{n_k})$ of $(\mu_n)$ so that $\int_X f \, \mathrm{d}\mu_k \to f(x)$ as $k\to\infty$ simultaneously for all $f \in \mathcal{D}$. Now it is routine to check that this implies $\mu_{n_k} \to \delta_x$ weakly.